# Print First Letter of Each Word in a String in Python (Keep Punctuation Marks)

Tags: python-3.x

First post to site so I apologize if I do something wrong. I have looked for an appropriate answer, but could not find one.

I am new to python and have been playing around trying to take a long string (passage in a book,) and printing all but the first letter of each word while keeping the punctuation marks (Though not apostrophe marks.) and have been unsuccessful so far.

Example:

```
input = "Hello, I'm writing a sentence. (Though not a good one.)"
```

Code....

```
output = H, I W A S. (T N A G O.)
```

--Note the ",", ".", "()", but not the " ' ".

Any tips? Thank you all so much for taking the time to look

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why it failed? Was there any specific error messages you failed to understand?

Answer (score 0):

To help you on your adventure, I'll give you like a step-by-step logic of it

In python first use the .split() to seperate it by spaces

Go through each string in the list

Go through every char in the string

Print any punctuation marks that you specify and the first alphabetical character you find